# Icon setVisible duplicating menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

In my action bar I have 2 menu items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/refresh"
          android:title="Refresh"
          android:icon="@drawable/refresh"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" >
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/back"
          android:title="Back"
          android:icon="@drawable/back"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" >
    </item>
</menu>
```

I'm trying to turn "invisible" my menu item "Refresh", when I call the function refreshinvisible(), the Refresh item goes away, but now the action bar shows two "back" items... Why? (I'm using SherlockActionBar)

My refreshinvisible() function:

```
public void refreshinvisible(){
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.refresh);
        item.setVisible(false);
}
```

Anyone know how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method called [onPrepareOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) which is called every time right before the menu is shown, i.e. *before* [onCreateOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) is called. You can use the activity's [invalidateOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29) method to trigger a redraw of the options menu.
Hence, you can easily re-create your menu taking into account certain conditions.

Here's some code. Define two booleans as fields of your class, for example:

```
private boolean showRefresh;
private boolean showBack;
```

Override the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` method and set the menu item's visbility depending on the respective `boolean`:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu( Menu menu ) {

    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu( menu );

    menu.findItem( R.id.refresh ).setVisible( showRefresh );
    menu.findItem( R.id.back ).setVisible( showBack );

    return true;
}
```

No every time you want to change the visibility of a certain menu item, set the respective `boolean` accordingly and call the `invalidateOptionsMenu()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html).

**Changing menu items at runtime**

> Once the activity is created, the
>   onCreateOptionsMenu() method is called
>   only once, as described above. The
>   system keeps and re-uses the Menu you
>   define in this method until your
>   activity is destroyed. If you want to
>   change the Options Menu any time after
>   it's first created, you must override
>   the onPrepareOptionsMenu() method.
>   This passes you the Menu object as it
>   currently exists. This is useful if
>   you'd like to remove, add, disable, or
>   enable menu items depending on the
>   current state of your application.

E.g.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
     MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.refresh);
     item.setVisible(false);
     return true;
}
```

Comment: Thus the item "refresh" become invisible when I run the activity. I wonder how do I make it invisible only when certain function is performed. Sorry, I'm very noob in java.